# Find the length of the chord and the distance between parallel chords, given their angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

The radius of a circle is 21.4 meter. Find the length of the chord subtended by a central angle of 110 degrees 40 minutes and the distance between two parallel chords on the same side of the center subtended by central angles 118 degrees 40 minutes and 52 degrees 20 minutes.

---

*Progress*:  I know the radius is 21.4 meter, I set up a triangle but my final answer was wrong.

Comment: Well I know the radius is 21.4 meter I set up a triangle but my final answer was wrong because I am not sure how to set it up.

Comment: draw perpendicular to the chord, the perpendicular will **bisect** the angle angle subtended at the center.

Comment: Please stop making titles that are descriptions followed by a question mark?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:

[image: chord]

You have $\dfrac{a}{r} = \sin \alpha$ and $\dfrac{b}{r} = \cos \alpha$.

You may have to take into account that some of these are half what you are interested in.

Comment: thank you for you illustration.

Comment: I see know that the length of the chord subtended by a central angle of 110 degrees 40 minutes is 35.2 thanks to your formula a/r sin a but I am having trouble doing the second part of my problem.

Comment: @Bishop: Try working out $b$ for both chords

Answer (score 1):

the radius of circle is 21.4m find (a) the length of the chord subtended by a central angle of 110°40' and (b) the distance between two parallel chords on the same side of the central subtended by central angles 118°40' and 52°20'

Comment: Remember to add LaTeX